# How to call a "final" variable in another class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call a `final` variable from another class in a string, but an error occurred: `Instance member 'country' can't be accessed using static access`.
The variable I want to call is `final String country` in the fifth line.
Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CountryDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> countries;
  final String country;
  final Function(String) onChanged;

  const CountryDropdown({
    @required this.countries,
    @required this.country,
    @required this.onChanged,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
      height: 40.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: country,
          items: countries
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 12.0,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/${e.toLowerCase()}_flag.png',
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                        Text(
                          e,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    value: e,
                  ))
              .toList(),
          onChanged: onChanged,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you can help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: `country` is not a `static` variable so you need a object instance of `CountryDropdown` to get the value from the object.

Comment: CountryDropdown().countries

Comment: @cpboyce Not a solution since that would just return `null`. Also, the named arguments is marked as `required` so your example would give an analyzer error or warning.